# How to populate Visualforce component List Using a method

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Hi I know I am missing something very small, but I don't know what is that, I want to call a method of vf component or something to populate a list of my vf component.

I am calling the vf component from my visualforce page, and then I want to populate another list, by calling another method

Here is what I want to do after my visualforce page calls my vf component

```
    public void populateAnotherList() {
        iteratorInst= new myIteratorClass(ListAttributeOfVFComponent);
        anotherList = iteratorInst.next();
    }
```

ListAttributeOfVFComponent this list is getting populated and but I am not able to populate "anotherList" as I am not able to call this above method of vf component.

Comment: how does the vf page looklike?

Comment: consider it normal, just using the vf component